Location of the maximizer of the sum of two concave and maximizable functions
This question follows up on the discussion in "Does the sum of two concave maximizable functions is maximizable?". Given that the sum of two concave, maximizable functions is itself maximizable, I am curious whether it is possible to identify the region where the maximizer of the sum is located.
Formally, let $f, g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be two concave and maximizable functions, with $x^f$ and $x^g$ denoting the respective maximizers of $f$ and $g$. Then, their sum $h = f + g$ is also concave and maximizable. The question is: can we explicitly characterize the region where the maximizer of $h$, denoted $x^h$, lies, using only the information about the maximizers $x^f$ and $x^g$?
There are cases (that I know) where this question is easy to answer. For example:

Univariate case ($n = 1$): By the Intermediate Value Theorem, the maximizer $x^h$ lies within the interval $[x^f, x^g]$.
Separable functions: If both $f$ and $g$ are separable, i.e., the sum of univariate concave functions in each coordinate, the Poincaré-Miranda Theorem ensures that the maximizer $x^h$ lies inside the hypercube defined by the opposite vertices $x^f$ and $x^g$.

These examples rely on relatively strong conditions, so I am curious whether weaker conditions on $f$ and $g$ might still allow us to identify the region where $x^h$ is located, solely in terms of $x^f$ and $x^g$.

I don't think so. For a domain with dimension of at least two, given an arbitrary point y that's not on the same line as $x_f,x_g$, define your functions to be
$f(x) = -||x- p_f(x)||$
Where $p_f(x) = p(x,x_f y)$ is the projection of $x$ on the line going through $x_f, y$. Similarly
$g(x) = -||x- p_g(x)||$
Now $y$ maximizes the f+g.
Here I'm taking advantage of the maximizers of $f$ and $g$ not being unique. I can do something close to this when they are unique too.
$f(x) = - \alpha ||x - p_f(x)|| - ||p_f(x)-x_f||$
$g(x) = - \alpha ||x - p_g(x)|| - ||p_g(x)-x_g||$
For big enough $\alpha$ the the argmax will get arbitrary closer to $y$ as the cost of being away from the any of the two lines will be huge.
The only thing we can dismiss is points on the line going through $x_f, x_g$ that are not between $x_f, x_g$(this is reduced to your $\mathbb{R}^1$ example).
